# Is a slight steering wheel vibration normal in a 2012 Civic when cold?

Tags: civic

I have been looking at a number of 2012 Honda Civics for consideration and each one I test drive has a slight vibration in the steering wheel when idle. Normally I know that vibrations in wheels are bad, but it is very cold around here (-10c on average).

Is this vibration normal at these temperatures on Civics? Or should I avoid any car which has this vibration as it may indicate a future repair?

Comment: Does this happen while the car itself is cold, then goes away once it warms up? Or does it happen all the time while the temp is cold?

Comment: @Paulster2 The test drives are 20 minutes, which should be long enough to warm the car, however the vibration generally remains.

Comment: Are you describing a vibration when sitting at a stop?  Or are you noticing vibration while driving?  Straight line?  Is there a difference between right turns and left turns?  At what speeds?

Comment: @BobCross Vibration only at idle. Seems to go away when in motion, or at least not noticeable.